# How to change label (image form) with next button python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am currently a novice in python and I'm trying to make a label switch from one image to another by clicking a next button. Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *

def next1():
    global slide
    slide=1
    if slide==1:
        bglabel.config(image=bg1)
    elif slide==2:
        bglabel.config(image=bg2)
    slide+=1
    window.update()

window=Tk()
window.geometry("1500x750+0+0")

bg1=PhotoImage(file="backslide1.png")
bg2=PhotoImage(file="backslide2.png")
nextbutton=PhotoImage(file="next.png")

bglabel=Label(window, image=bg1)
bglabel.place(x=600,y=200)

nextbutton1=Button(window, image=nextbutton, bd=0, command=next1())

window.bind('<Button-1>', next1())
```

I sat for a good hour or so trying to tamper with the slide variable (trying to declare it before def, removing global, changing value, changing where slide+=1 is, etc) but one of two things always happens; either it's stuck on bg1 with the button clicking but doing nothing, or jumping straight to bg2. I've also tried splitting next1 into two different def's, one for variable tracking, one for switching bglabel, but still the same output. Please help.

(Also, will that window.bind be trouble as I continue to add buttons? If so please let me know how to do it correctly.)

Comment: Followed bind+button fix suggestion from @Ernxst

Comment: Fixed variable from @Novel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, one 'error' that occurs is that the image immediately jumps to image `bg2`. This is the line causing that:

```
nextbutton1=Button(window, image=nextbutton, bd=0, command=next1())
```

More specifically, where you declare the command associated with the button:

```
command=next1()
```

With the enclosed brackets, you're calling the function `next1` i.e. as soon as the button is created, run the specified function.

To solve this, just remove the pair of brackets:

```
nextbutton1=Button(window, image=nextbutton, bd=0, command=next1)
```

The same goes for your key binding. This way, the button/key now has a reference to the function - it knows what function to run and will run it when the specified action is performed.

More about the key binding... 
When you use `bind` to assign a key to run a function, whatever function that is to be run needs to be made aware as such. Currently, the `next` function you are trying to bind is given no indication that it can be called using a keyboard button event. To fix that, we set a default parameter in `next` specifying the event:

```
def next1(event=None):
    #rest of function code here

window.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: next(event))
```

Setting a default parameter, `event=None`, basically means if no value for`event` was passed to the function from whatever called it, set it to `None` by default (in that sense, you can choose to set it to whatever by default). Using `lambda` for the key bind in this way allows us to pass parameters to functions. We specify what parameter(s) we want to pass to the function and then specify the function, with the parameter(s) enclosed in brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the function, not the result of the function. So no parenthesis. Like this:

```
nextbutton1=Button(window, image=nextbutton, bd=0, command=next1)
```

Also remove the `window.bind` line, and your loop logic is broken. "slide" is always 1 since you set that in the function. Are you trying to cycle between the 2 images with every click? If so use `itertools.cycle`:

```
from tkinter import *
from itertools import cycle

def next1():
    bglabel.config(image=next(bgimages))

window=Tk()
window.geometry("1500x750+0+0")

bg1=PhotoImage(file="backslide1.png")
bg2=PhotoImage(file="backslide2.png")
bgimages = cycle([bg1, bg2])
nextbutton=PhotoImage(file="next.png")

bglabel=Label(window)
bglabel.place(x=600,y=200)
next1() # set the first image

nextbutton1=Button(window, image=nextbutton, bd=0, command=next1)
nextbutton1.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

(totally untested since i don't have your images).